# Gorilla Sessions - How to Automatically Update Cookie Expiration on Request?

Tags: session, cookies, go, session-timeout, gorilla

I know many other languages and web frameworks will automatically update a cookie's expiration time to the session timeout every time a session is accessed via the backend (or some action like that).  I don't believe Gorilla provides this utility.

I am consider just writing some request middleware that, if it detects a valid session, will extend the cookie lifetime but I am wondering if there is a better method of doing this.

What are the best practices for updating cookie expiration, especially as they pertain to Gorilla/Go?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply implement your own [`Store`](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions#Store) that builds on top of an existing session store like the `CookieStore`, but uses some rule to automatically update the expiration during a `Save` call.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the Max-Age parameter of the cookie, you don't need to set Expiry as well, unless you need to support old browsers that don't understand Max-Age.

Using only Max-Age means you don't need to update it on every request.

Set the spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2

Comment: Right but max-age is relative to the cookie creation.  So I guess in this case I need to destroy the old session, and create a new, identical one?

Comment: Fair point. Just a new Set-Cookie header will do, updating the existing one if you use the same name, path, domain etc. But this takes you back to your original question.

Comment: Yeah, I just ended up setting a "created" Unix timestamp on my session upon login.  Then, I wrote request middleware that would set `session.Options.MaxAge = time.Now().Unix() - session.Values["created"].(int64) + sessionStore.SessionLengthSeconds`.  I also had to make sure that this middleware would run before any response was generated as saving session sets the "Set-Cookie" header.