# Logout only if idle

Tags: session, go, gorilla

I am using [gorilla/sessions](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions) for session handling. Below is my code for session:

```
var STORE = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("some_secret_text"))

session, err := STORE.Get(c.Request, "user")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error: ",err)
}
if session.IsNew {
   session.Options.MaxAge = 10 * 60
}
```

I want to logout user only if he is idle for 10 minutes. 
Currently user gets logged out even if he is working.

Comment: What does "working" mean for your application. Gorilla/Sessions does not seems to provide anything to do what you ask out of the box. Perhaps you could recreate a cookie, update its expiration date, if the user you want to keep logged-in has sent a request in the last 5 minutes...

Comment: Working means user is using web app. If he is performing any activity (like visiting menus or any back end process related to browser request) then he should not logged out of the system.

Comment: Well, either you increment that 10minutes expiration timeout, or you implement a system to detect user-activity and update the cookie expiration date based on that.

Comment: See [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616830/gorilla-sessions-how-to-automatically-update-cookie-expiration-on-request)

Answer (score 2):

I had some good experience using https://github.com/alexedwards/scs for session-handling.

It also includes a setting for idle-timeout:

```
session.IdleTimeout(30*time.Minute)
```

I don't know if switching the session-library is an option for you, but scs integrates pretty seamlessly, so it might be worth looking at it at least. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code that I use to do this:

```
func SessionHandler(ses sessions.Session, timeout int64) {
    timeNow := time.Now().Unix()

    if ses.Get("authenticated").(bool) {
        switch ses.Get("timestamp").(type) {
        case int64:
            sessiontime := ses.Get("timestamp").(int64)

            if sessiontime > 0 {
                if timeNow > (sessiontime + timeout) {
                    ses.Clear()
                    ses.Save()
                    return
                }

                ses.Set("timestamp", timeNow)
                ses.Save()
            }
        default:
            ses.Set("timestamp", timeNow)
            ses.Save()
        }
    }
}
```